# SQL - applying multiple pivots in one query, and finding the sum of resulting rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to create an SQL query which will compress multidimentional data using PIVOT, but need to do some operations on the pivoted data.

I have coding experience but very little experience with SQL and am using SQLPathfinder3 to create and execute queries, so what I am looking for is top level approach - what order of operations should I be going for here to achieve the desired result?

An example of my initial result table, gotten with SELECT, is as follows:

| Item | Property | Subproperty | Thing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | propertyA | subproperty1 | value1_A_1 |
| item1 | propertyA | subproperty2 | value1_A_2 |
| item1 | propertyB | subproperty1 | value1_B_1 |
| item1 | propertyB | subproperty2 | value1_B_2 |
| item2 | propertyA | subproperty1 | value2_A_1 |
| item2 | propertyA | subproperty2 | value2_A_2 |
| item2 | propertyB | subproperty1 | value2_B_1 |
| item2 | propertyB | subproperty2 | value2_B_2 |

By executing one pivot, assigning Subproperty as the CTHEADER, and Thing as the CTVALUE, I can create this:

| Item | Property | Subproperty1 | Subproperty2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | propertyA | value1_A_1 | value1_A_2 |
| item1 | propertyB | value1_B_1 | value1_B_2 |
| item2 | propertyA | value2_A_1 | value2_A_2 |
| item2 | propertyB | value2_B_1 | value2_B_2 |

Similarly, I can pivot around "Subproperty" to get something analogous:

| Item | Subproperty | Property A | Property B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | subproperty1 | value1_A_1 | value1_A_2 |
| item1 | subproperty2 | value1_B_1 | value1_B_2 |
| item2 | subproperty1 | value2_A_1 | value2_A_2 |
| item2 | subproperty2 | value2_B_1 | value2_B_2 |

The final result that I need is this - a combination of the above values:

| Item | Property A | Property B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | value1_A_1 + value1_A_2 | value1_B_1 + value1_B_2 |
| item2 | value2_A_1 + value2_A_2 | value2_B_1 + value2_B_2 |

I don't know how to go about doing this in a single query, but I would very much like to, because this is something that needs to be automated.

I can't simply SELECT the sums that I want, because those values are on four separate lines. I could workaround in excel or python, especially if I can effect the result below, but I'm not sure how to do this.

| Item | PropA Sub1 | PropA Sub2 | PropB Sub1 | PropB Sub2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | value1_A_1 | value1_A_2 | value1_B_1 | value1_B_2 |
| item2 | value2_A_1 | value2_A_2 | value2_B_1 | value2_B_2 |

Any help, or pointers towards educational material would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description. But in my opinion, it's very difficult to think about a correct query when you don't provide the original sample input. As I understand your question, none of the tables above show your input data, even not the first one. They are all results of queries (that you haven't shown us). Could you please provide a fiddle and show the real input data?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I thing the first " initial result" table is the initial data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    P.Item,
    STRING_AGG(P.propertyA, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Subproperty) AS propertyA,
    STRING_AGG(P.propertyB, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Subproperty) AS propertyB
FROM @Data
PIVOT (
    MAX(Thing)
    FOR Property IN (propertyA, propertyB)
) P
GROUP BY P.Item
ORDER BY P.Item
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_TpGLjkO).

The initial `PIVOT` will yield:

| Item | Subproperty | propertyA | propertyB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | subproperty1 | value1_A_1 | value1_B_1 |
| item2 | subproperty1 | value2_A_1 | value2_B_1 |
| item1 | subproperty2 | value1_A_2 | value1_B_2 |
| item2 | subproperty2 | value2_A_2 | value2_B_2 |

and the `GROUP BY` and `STRING_AGG()` will yield the desired result:

| Item | propertyA | propertyB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | value1_A_1 + value1_A_2 | value1_B_1 + value1_B_2 |
| item2 | value2_A_1 + value2_A_2 | value2_B_1 + value2_B_2 |

The `WITHIN GROUP(...)` clause is not actually required, but guarantees consistent results.

ADDENDUM: For the case where a sum of numbers is need, the `STRING_AGG() WITHIN GROUP()` can be replaced with a simple `SUM()`. Using `SUM()` instead of `MAX()` in the pivot is also recommended.

```
-- Pivot plus group by aggregation (Sum of numeric values)
SELECT
    P.Item,
    SUM(P.propertyA) AS propertyA,
    SUM(P.propertyB) AS propertyB
FROM @Data
PIVOT (
    SUM(Thing)
    FOR Property IN (propertyA, propertyB)
) P
GROUP BY P.Item
ORDER BY P.Item
```

The Query can be further simplified to a plain old `PIVOT` by eliminating  unwanted columns from the initial select that feeds the `PIVOT`.

```
-- Using just a regular PIVOT after excluding unwanted columns
SELECT P.Item, P.propertyA, P.propertyB
FROM (SELECT Item, Property, Thing FROM @Data) D
PIVOT (
    SUM(Thing)
    FOR Property IN (propertyA, propertyB)
) P
```

Lastly (I hope), a technique called "Conditional Aggregation" can be used in place of the `PIVOT`. Sometimes this is actually easier to read, understand, and maintain.

```
-- Using conditional aggregation instead of PIVOT
SELECT
    D.Item,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.Property = 'propertyA' THEN D.Thing END) AS propertyA,
    SUM(CASE WHEN D.Property = 'propertyB' THEN D.Thing END) AS propertyB
FROM @Data D
GROUP BY D.Item
ORDER BY D.Item
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PzpipX4q) for the above techniques.

Comment: This is helpful, but I forgot to make it clear that I was using "value1_A_1" etc. as a stand-in for an integer. I need to actually add the values, not concatenate strings with a " + ".

Comment: In that case, the whole `STRING_AGG(P.propertyA, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Subproperty)` expression could just be replaced with `SUM(P.propertyA)`, and similarly for  `P.propertyB`.

Comment: See [this updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8lV5JIYZ) or [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/Eoj8X3FE) with different data.

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful. My limited SQL experience and the large complexity of the database i'm mining is making it hard to provide more info for other commenters unfortunately, but this will get me there I think.

Comment: One late addition, suggest that you change `MAX(Thing)` to `SUM(Thing)` in the `PIVOT` portion of the query also, in case there are ever multiple records with the same item and property names.

Comment: @Nathan I'll throw out a couple more options. Since `Subproperty` appears not to factor into the result at all, you can simplify the `PIVOT` by excluding `Subproperty` from the source select list. Also, it may be worth looking at a technique called "conditional aggregation" where a `CASE` statement is used to selectively include or exclude data from a `SUM()` or other function.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PzpipX4q) for all of the techniques mentioned so far.

Comment: @T N, Subproperty is important as it's the field that the added-together properties have in common.

Comment: The main issue I am currently having is I assumed that I could extend the answer to subtraction vs. addition. Is there a version of your solution which allows me to instead subtract the value for Subproperty1 from that of Subproperty2?

Comment: You could create a conditional `CASE Subproperty WHEN 'subproperty1' THEN 1 WHEN 'subproperty2' THEN -1 ELSE ??? END` and multiply that with the `Thing` value early in the process, prior to the first `SUM()`. In your original post, your sample "final result" data did not indicate a sign difference in the results (`value1_A_1 + value1_A_2`) which is why the solutions so far had no special processing for `Subproperty`. Is there anything else important that has not been shared? I'm happy to donate some of my time, but prefer not to spend it heading down a dead end.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose a dynamic approach, as property will have morwe than 2 item i guess.

I choose to use integers for thig as you wante4d sums

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
    ([Item] varchar(5), [Property] varchar(9), [Subproperty] varchar(12), [Thing] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO tab1
    ([Item], [Property], [Subproperty], [Thing])
VALUES
    ('item1', 'propertyA', 'subproperty1', 1),
    ('item1', 'propertyA', 'subproperty2', 2),
    ('item1', 'propertyB', 'subproperty1', 3),
    ('item1', 'propertyB', 'subproperty2', 4),
    ('item2', 'propertyA', 'subproperty1', 5),
    ('item2', 'propertyA', 'subproperty2', 6),
    ('item2', 'propertyB', 'subproperty1', 7),
    ('item2', 'propertyB', 'subproperty2', 8)
;
```

```
8 rows affected
```

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = (SELECT STRING_AGG([Property],',') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Property] FROM tab1 WHERE [Property] IS NOT NULL)t);

set @query = '
  
  SELECT [Item], ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                SELECT
                   [Item], [Property], SUM([Thing]) as SumThing
                 FROM tab1
                 GROUP BY [Item], [Property]
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 SUM(SumThing)
                for [Property] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';

execute(@query);
```

| Item | propertyA | propertyB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 3 | 7 |
| item2 | 11 | 15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GSpTncW0)